# django-allauth DefaultAccountAdapter clean_password() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have written my own custom account adapter using django-allauth and django 1.10, so that I can specify a regex patterns for passwords to be validated.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def clean_password(self, password):
        if re.match(settings.ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_REGEX, password):
            return password
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Password must be at least 8 characters long, contain one digit and one captalised alphabet")
```

I have specified to use this class in my **settings.py**:

`ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'app.adapters.MyAccountAdapter'`

When I attempt to sign up (i.e. submit a filled in form), I get the following error:

> TypeError at /accounts/signup/
>
> clean_password() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

**Traceback:**

```
File "/path/to/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "/path/to/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/path/to/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/path/to/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/path/to/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/path/to/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/path/to/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/path/to/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in dispatch
  205.         return super(SignupView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/path/to/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in dispatch
  74.                                             **kwargs)

File "/path/to/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in dispatch
  183.                                                           **kwargs)

File "/path/to/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/path/to/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in post
  96.         if form.is_valid():

File "/path/to/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  169.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/path/to/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  161.             self.full_clean()

File "/path/to/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  371.         self._clean_form()

File "/path/to/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  398.             cleaned_data = self.clean()

File "/path/to/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py" in clean
  363.                     user=dummy_user)

Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/signup/
Exception Value: clean_password() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
```

What's the meaning of this cryptic error, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `DefaultAccountAdapter` implementation of `clean_password`:

```
def clean_password(self, password, user=None):
        """
        Validates a password. You can hook into this if you want to
        restric the allowed password choices.
        """
```

You are missing the `user` keyword parameter.

Comment: Gah!, I realised the function signature was different - when I searched through the source code.

Comment: Happens to me all the time, thanks for the vote though :D